# MFC button can not receive touch event or mouse event

Tags: mfc, touch, mouse

The list control can receive the touch event, but the push button or textedit can not receive the touch event, it always receive the mouse move event.

code like below can tell if it is a mouse or touch event, but when flick up & down for a while, it can not receive the event.

Then flick left & right can always receive the mouse move event

```
#define MOUSEEVENTF_FROMTOUCH 0xFF515700

if ((GetMessageExtraInfo() & MOUSEEVENTF_FROMTOUCH) == MOUSEEVENTF_FROMTOUCH) { 
// Click was generated by wisptis / Windows Touch
}else{ 
// Click was generated by the mouse.
}
```

I put this button in a scrollview which has the vertical scroll bar.

Comment: Did you called RegisterTouchWindow for every window? Did you subclass the button to handle the WM_TOUCH message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, at last, microsoft replaced touch event with pointer event.